# GRASS GIS Segmentation issue on UAV image

Tags: grass-gis, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, image-segmentation

I tried [i.segment](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/i.segment.html) to perform segmentation on a part of UAV orthophoto image, but this always results in stripe-like rectangle segments which I do not expect. Could anyone figure out what happens?

Please let me note that [r.info](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.info.html) returns the size of this image as 6075 rows and 4525 columns, but [g.region i -p](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/g.region.html) returns only 86 rows and 7 columns.

The settings for image segmentation were as follows:

```
input: 3 bands (RGB) of raster maps
threshold: 0.01
minimum # of segment: 1
max. iteration: 100
others: default
```

[image: 1]][3](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/g.region.html)

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post the outputs of: `g.region -p` and `r.info ...` for each of the three bands. Also `i.group -l group=<your_image_group>`. And last, the full `i.segment` command that you ran.